# how to update user table in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

**mycode is--**

```
 updateUser: function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    var option = {
        name: data.name,
        mobile: data.mobile,
        domain: data.domain,
    }
    userModel.update(option, function (error, rows) {
        console.log('###############',error || rows);
        if(!res){
            //TODO: Error handling
            console.log("ERROR", res);
            res.status(200).send({"status_code": 0, 'message': 'Some error occured'});
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).send({"status_code": 1, 'message': 'Succesfully Updated'});
    })
},
```

**the problem is updated all user coloumn.**

**in the code how to give id of the particular update data.**

Comment: You don't say what technologies you are using. Mongoose?

Comment: NO. I am using MySql database.

Comment: What javascript library are you using to connect to it? Where does `userModel.update` come from?

Comment: in Model---- user.js------    update: function (options, cb) {
    var query;
    options.created_at = new Date();
    query = this.table.update(options);
    query.exec(updateUser);
    function updateUser(err, res){
      if(err){
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, res.insertId);
    }
  }
};

Comment: var userModel = require('../model/user');

Comment: connection.query('UPDATE users SET Name = :Name WHERE UserID = :UserID',
                     {UserID: userId, Name: name})

Answer (score 1):

If you are not writing some very low level driver, I would recommend to use ORM like https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize. The very first example on their homepage shows:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  return User.create({
    username: 'janedoe',
    birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
  });
}).then(function(jane) {
  console.log(jane.get());
  jane.update({
       username: 'a very different username now'
  }).then(function() {
       console.log(jane.get());
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Bookshelf.js](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/), good ORM, easy to use